# Adding Migration in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I run Add-Migration It gives me error blow:
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Here are my codes:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using nftipy.Context;
using nftipy.Interface;
using nftipy.Repository;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUser, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(option => 
    option.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NftipyDb;Integrated Security=true"));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using nftipy.Models;

namespace nftipy.Context
{
        public partial class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
        {
            public DatabaseContext()
            {
            }

            public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasNoKey();
                    entity.ToTable("Users");
                    entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
                    entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(30).IsUnicode(false);
                    entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(false);
                    entity.Property(e => e.Password).HasMaxLength(20).IsUnicode(false);
                });
                OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasData(
                new User
                {
                    UserId = 1,
                    UserName = "Admin",
                    Email = "business.kam20i@gmail.com",
                    Password = "Admin1234"
                }
                );

            }

            

            partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.* Are you doing that?

Comment: Based on the error message (and if I remember correctly) you should either remove Default Constructor (and keep only the one with DbContextOptions) or override OnConfiguring

Comment: It sounds like the tools can't use your application services for some reason. What is the output with `--verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a design time factory.  This allows you to have full control over both what happens to the context during the migration creation and in addition allows full control over constructors.  I store this class in the same project as my migrations.

```
 class MyContextDesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
 
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MyConnString"));

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for more info.